# CAST int to DATE failure when used with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
T2.PseudoDateColumn
FROM
    (
    SELECT
    *
    FROM T1
    WHERE
    PseudoDateColumn <> -1
    ) T2
INNER JOIN T3
    ON T2.T2_key = T3.T3_key  
WHERE
CAST(CAST(T2.PseudoDateColumn AS VARCHAR) AS DATE) 
BETWEEN 
DATEADD(mm, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 
AND DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(mm, 0, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
```

`PseudoDateColumn` is an `int` in `T1`. Values that aren't real dates have a `-1` placeholder.  All other dates are real dates (just stored as an `int`).  Because of this, I need to first filter out all of the `-1` values before I cast `PseudoDateColumn` to a `DATE`, such that I can use `BETWEEN`.  When I run this script without the `join`, it works fine. But, when I run it with the `join`, SQL throws an error:

> "conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string"

I don't know why this is happening. It's like SQL is doing the CASTing even before the sub-query.

**Update**:
I mistakenly wrote SQL Server 2008.  I'm actually running this on **PDW AU5**, which has SQL Server 2012.  I don't think that makes a difference, though.

Also, here is some sample data in `PseudoDateColumn`.  All values are in the form YYYYMMDD.

```
PseudoDateColumn
-----------------
20150112
20160305
20111009
```

Comment: Show a sample of what a PseudoDateColumn value looks like.

Comment: Suggestion: change the data type to `DATE` and use `NULL` (which means no valid value) instead of meaningless tokens like -1.

Comment: Always explicitly define varchar length, e.g. `cast(.. as varchar(8))`. Don't understand why are you casting since it is already a varchar col.

Comment: Actually, it's not a varchar.  It's an int.  To get to DATE, I think I need to go through VARCHAR first.

Comment: Also, you say you don't know why it is happening, it's because you assume SQL Server will process all the parts of your query in the order your wrote them, or brackets first like math, etc. This is not true - SQL Server is free to process any part of your query first, including evaluating columns or expressions [in an illogical order](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors). The way you defeat this is, instead of saying `CAST(something AS date)`, say `CASE WHEN ISDATE(something) THEN CASE(something AS date)`.

Comment: But, honestly, the real problem is that you're using the wrong data type in the first place.

Comment: It's not my table, and I can't alter it.  How can you use a CASE WHEN ... THEN in a WHERE clause?

Comment: `WHERE CASE WHEN ISDATE(T2.col) = 1 THEN CAST(CAST(T2.col AS CHAR(10)) AS DATE) ELSE NULL END BETWEEN...`. Also, please, please, please read up on these: [schema references](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) | [varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) | [between and the stupid 3 millisecond trick](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: And [the lazy shorthand (type `MONTH`!)](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx) and the [risky datediff calculation](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/datediff-bug). Here's a [much cleaner query](http://pastebin.com/jnNVYQJw). Please read all of these links I'm providing - you are violating a lot of bad habits and they will bite you if you don't understand them.

Comment: @Aaron: I totally agree that I was being lazy in my example.  I should have written dbo. in front of my tables, specified the varchar length, used an open-ended data range instead of BETWEEN, and spelled out MONTH in my DATEDIFF.  In fact, I almost always follow those best practices.  I wasn't previously aware of the intricacies with DATEDIFF.  Thank you for keeping me honest.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I think this can help someone. I had a similar error when trying to convert/cast a `VARCHAR` input parameter to a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` in my inner join. All my data was valid and the conversion worked just fine if done outside the join, but it would fail *during* the join. In fact I was even getting results in the results pane of SQL Server Management Studio but the error was still being thrown. What worked for me was to use `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` instead of `CAST` or `CONVERT`. My friendly neighborhood DBA suggested this solution because it ensures *early execution* or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation for the behavior is a "bad" value stored in the `PseudoDateColumn`.  But you should be able to debug that.

Storing "date" values in an integer column seems like an anti-pattern to me, when SQL Server has a perfectly suitable `DATE` datatype custom designed for storing date values.

But if you need to work with what you already have, and address the issue without altering the schema definition...

SQL Server has an `ISDATE` function that you could use test test the validity of a character string. Unfortunately, the check that `ISDATE` performs isn't as strict as an actual `CAST` operation, but it does catch the most egregiously "bad" values.

**My recommendation:**

Instead of converting the integers to dates (the integer values stored in your column...

Cast/convert your literal DATE values to integer, into the same datatype/format as the column (integer), and do the comparison to the raw integer column.

So your query would be something like this:

```
WHERE T2.PseudoDateColumn >= CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), datexpr1, 112) )
  AND T2.PseudoDateColumn <  CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), datexpr2, 112) )
```

In that example, **`dateexpr1`** and **`dateexpr2`** would be replaced with expressions that return a `DATE` datatype, like the expressions in the original query.

NOTE: This type of range comparison depends on the stored integer values to be canonical. (With year first (four digits), then month (two digits), then day (two digits). In that representation, we are guaranteed that the comparison

```
 (int)a  <= (int)b  < (int)c
```

will yield the same results as

```
 (date)a <= (date)b < (date)c
```

(Equivalent apart from the differences due to "bad" integer values that can't be converted to a valid date... for example, an integer value with invalid "month" and/or "day" parts, e.g. `20161300`  (month is thirteen, and day is zero)

An integer comparison that checks for pseudodates the 2016 would "work" for that without throwing an error...

```
20160101 <= 20161300 < 2017000    -> TRUE
```

This approach entirely avoids the issue of attempting to convert a "bad" psuedodate integer value into a `DATE`.  But it's always possible to convert a valid DATE into an integer in `YYYYMMDD` format.

As an added benefit of this pattern, with predicates on the bare `PseudoDateColumn` column, SQL Server may be able to make effective use of an index that has `PseudoDateColumn` as the leading column.

---

If you are dead set on converting `PseudoDateColumn` to a DATE, you could first perform a conditional test that validates the value, using the `ISDATE` function. Something like this:

```
  CASE WHEN ISDATE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), T2.PsedoDateColumn)) = 1
    THEN CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), T2.PseudoDateColumn),112)
    ELSE NULL
  END
```